# Navigation with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In [react-router-dom](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom) there is an option to send data between pages in the url
for example `myBurger/?bacon=2&salad=3`

My question is if there is a service that make the (bacon,salad) data string from an object...
for example

```
var ingredients = {
  salad: 3,
  bacon: 2
}

myCustomServiceConverter.FromObjectToString(ingredients);
// return ?bacon=2&salad=3
```

And in the next page will be function that decoding it back

```
var URL = http://localhost:3000/myBurger/?bacon=2&salad=3
myCustomServiceConverter.FromStringToObject(URL);
// return { salad: 3, bacon: 2 }
```

please do not suggest those [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp)

Comment: Why would you want to pass data using url-parameters? there is much more sophisticated ways to do data handling.

Comment: You mean with redux?
if i dont want to use redux and i want to keep it simple why not to use url params.... @JimiPajala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it by using a library named qs

You can find doc here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs

```
let url = qs.stringify({salad: 3,
  bacon: 2
})
```

and then getting back the object

using another library named query-string

https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

```
 let url = this.props.history.location.state.query;
 let object = queryString.parse(url, {arrayFormat: 'index'})
```

Comment: Totally what i'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I've build a little plugin for this kind of operations, maybe you could give it a try [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/queryfy).

Comment: Sorry but you dont supported nested object and arrays :/